# The name of a quartic curve: The product of the distance to the focus and to the directrix is the constant.

Tags: terminology, algebraic-curves, locus

It is like a question of the natural history in math, but I would like to know if the locus has a particular name.  The equation of the curve is
$(x+1)^2((x-1)^2+y^2)=1$.
The curve includes a similar shape to Folium of Descartes which is cubic, but it has another part in the opposite side of the directrix: $x=-1$.
The quartic curves formed in which the product of the distances to the two foci is constant have the names of Cassinian oval, but I could not find the name of this particular curve.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think that it is more likely to get a good answer at [hsm.se].  It might also be worth noting that this is a question about the history of mathematics, not the natural history of mathematics.